# C# Error when reading Xml Attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I'm developing my first WPF application with C# but I have a problem when I'm trying to read a Xml attribute.

I have the following Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dictionary EnglishName="Italian" CultureName="Italian" Culture="">
    <!-- MainWindow -->
    <Value ID="WpfApplication1.MainWindow.BtnDrawCircle" Content="Circonferenza"/>
    <Value ID="WpfApplication1.MainWindow.BtnDrawLine" Content="Linea"/>
    ....
    ....
</Dictionary>`
```

Now I try to get the Attribute "Content" with the following method:

```
public static string ReadNodeAttribute(string IDAttribute)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
            _Doc.Load("myPath\\Language\\it-IT.xml");

            string _Value = _Doc.SelectSingleNode("//Value[@ID=" + IDAttribute + "]").Attributes["Content"].Value.ToString();

            return _Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work:

> Error : ex    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: "it dosn't work". Can you be more spesific about what dosnt work exactly? What exactly are you passing for `IDAttribute`?

Comment: To IDAttribute I try to pass this "WpfApplication1.MainWindow.BtnDrawCircle".... but I receive the follwing Error : ex {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: The way to do this stuff isn't to write a big wodge of code with multiple points of failure, and then try to guess where it failed. Build it up one little piece at a time. First, try `var xn = _Doc.SelectSingleNode("//Value[@ID=" + IDAttribute + "]");` and see what you get for `xn`. You can use the watch window in the debugger. Once you figure out the right xpath expression to get the node you want, you can look at its `Attributes` collection *in the debugger* and see what is in there. For all I know, the relative path to your file may be wrong. Check _Doc after Load!

Comment: In case you will try to get "IDAttribute" that doesn't exist in the xml you will get this error, that's why in my answer I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got

> null reference exception

because you didn't check for **null** in case your **IDAttribute** doesn't exist in the **XML**.

Just change to your path and it will work.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

  public static string ReadNodeAttribute(string IDAttribute)
        {
            string _Value = "";
            try
            {
               //I used System.IO.Path.GetFullPath because I tried it with ConsoleApplication.
               //Use what ever work for you to load the xml.
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
                var myValue = xdoc.Descendants("Value").FirstOrDefault(i => i.Attribute("ID").Value == IDAttribute);
                if (myValue != null)
                {
                    _Value = myValue.Attribute("Content").Value;

                    return _Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return _Value;
        }
```

Comment: It Work Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using `Linq to Xml`

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("path"));
 var val = xdoc.Descendants("Value").Where(i => i.Attribute("ID").Value == IDAttribute).FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Content").Value;
```

Inorder to use this you have to include `System.Xml.Linq` namespace